# Cannot show video ads from Smaato Ads for my Android App

Tags: android, ads, smaato

I am trying to implement Smaato Video Ads on my Android App.
     I have followed the instructions from the Smaato page and the Smaato example app and yet, I cannot manage to show the Smaato Video Ads.
     The code that apparently should show a video ad in fullscreen is:

```
private static Video smaatoVideoAd; // A Smaato Video global variable

smaatoVideoAd = new Video(this.getApplicationContext());
smaatoVideoAd.getAdSettings().setPublisherId(0); //int of 0 is supposedly a test mode
//smaatoVideoAd.getAdSettings().setPublisherId(PublisherID);
smaatoVideoAd.getAdSettings().setAdspaceId(0);  //int of 0 is supposedly a test mode
//smaatoVideoAd.getAdSettings().setAdspaceId(VideoAd_ID);
smaatoVideoAd.setVastAdListener(this);
smaatoVideoAd.setAutoCloseDuration(5);
smaatoVideoAd.disableAutoClose(true);
smaatoVideoAd.setVideoSkipInterval(3);
} // End of onCreate

// Called when the video has been loaded.
@Override
public void onReadyToShow() {
    // Call this when you want to show the video ad.
    smaatoVideoAd.show();
}

@Override
    public void onWillShow() {
    // Called when the ad will show.
}

@Override
public void onWillOpenLandingPage() {
    // Called when the banner has been clicked.
}

@Override
public void onWillClose() {
    // Called when Interstitial ad will be closed.
}

@Override
public void onFailedToLoadAd() {
    // called when video failed to load.
}
```

The Smaato libs for build.gradle has been setup, and that is pretty straightforward and short:

```
 repositories {
 ...
     flatDir {
         dirs 'libs'
     }
 ...
 }

 dependencies {
 ...
     implementation name:'SOMAAndroid-9.1.3-release', ext:'aar'
 ...
 }
```

And in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" />

 <meta-data android:name=”com.google.android.gms.version” android:value=”@integer/google_play_services_version”/>
 <activity android:name="com.smaato.soma.interstitial.InterstitialActivity" android:resizeableActivity="false" android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
 <activity android:name="com.smaato.soma.video.VASTAdActivity" android:resizeableActivity="false" android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
 <activity android:name="com.smaato.soma.ExpandedBannerActivity" android:resizeableActivity="false" android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
```

Besides, Smaato declares that: "*Since v8.0.0, the Smaato Android SDK contains an automatic initialization routine. Therefore there is no need for publishers to manually call an additional SDK initialization method*".

But running this code, gives me the following alert in the Logcat:

**SOMA_VIDEO: Video must be loaded before showing it**

So, the video add is not loading at all. What am I missing here?
Can you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Apparently, I hadn't the correct sequence order. With this order, the warning in Logcat vanishes:

```
    smaatoVideoAd = new Video(this.getApplicationContext());
    smaatoVideoAd.setVastAdListener(this);
    smaatoVideoAd.setAutoCloseDuration(3);
    smaatoVideoAd.disableAutoClose(false);
    smaatoVideoAd.setVideoSkipInterval(1);

    smaatoVideoAd.getAdSettings().setPublisherId(0); // Trial Publisher Id: 0
    smaatoVideoAd.getAdSettings().setAdspaceId(3090); // Trial Adspace Id for video: 3090
    smaatoVideoAd.asyncLoadNewBanner();
```

Notice that the code for Smaato video ad in trial mode is 3090, not 0. Also, I have put the Smaato Ad in a new activity, so closing the ad will close the child activity and not my main one.